# Normalizer of an open subgroup of a compact group

Tags: group-theory, compactness, topological-groups

For some reason I cannot figure out the following.

> Suppose $G$ is a compact, Hausdorff and totally disconnected (but I think compact should suffice) group and $U$ an open subgroup. Why is the normalizer of $U$ open?

This was mentioned in a book I read some time ago but I don't see why.

Edit: As said below  $U \subseteq N(U)$ and therefore $\infty > [G:U] > [G:N(U)]$.

Comment: because it contains $U$

Comment: Ah yes of course, I get it.

Comment: The finiteness of indices is a red herring. A supergroup of an open group is always open, being a union of open sets (viz. cosets of the smaller group). This works in any topological group, you don’t need it to be compact or Hausdorff.

Comment: See also "Subgroups of finite index in profinite groups" http://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/FLTJensen.pdf.